# Why isn't the child controller being loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, frontend

I'm trying to create a parent and children controller structure that contains common functions necessary for all child controllers in the parent controller. When I try to change from an unrelated state to one of the children, only the parent controller is run.

I've tried messing around with abstract controllers, all different forms of declaring a child and a parent (using dot notation, using parent = 'parentControllerName'), and nothing seems to work.

Random controller somewhere in the code

```
changeToLoginEmail() => {
    $state.go('login.email');
}
```

When I call changeToLoginEmail, this is then routed through my routes.js

```
angular.module('myModule')
    .config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {

            $stateProvider
                .state('login', { // Parent Controller
                    abstract: true,
                    url: '/login',
                    views: {
                        "master": {
                            controller: 'loginController'
                        }
                    }
                })
                .state('login.email', { // One of the children
                    url: '/login/email',
                    views: {
                        "email": {
                            controller: 'loginEmailController',
                            templateUrl: '/components/loginEmail/loginEmailView.html'
                        }
                    }
                })
    }
]);
```

Here are the two controllers:

loginController:

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .controller('loginController', loginController);

    function loginController($scope, $state) {
        console.log("state", $state);
        console.log("scope", $scope);
    }

    loginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];
})()
```

loginEmailController:

```
(() => {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myModule')
        .controller('loginEmailController', loginEmailController);

    function loginEmailController($scope, $state) {
        console.log("I was loaded woopie");
    }

    loginEmailController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state'];
})()
```

I expected the parent controller to be loaded first and then the child controller to be loaded. However, only the first two console.logs are printed in the console, while the loginEmailController's console.log never runs. The result is no view being loaded.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Are you sure you need `/login/email` in the child for 'url', and not just `/email`?

Comment: I'm not sure of anything by this point. But neither variation works.

It appears it was indeed unnecessary, so thank you for that :) Problem still persists though.

Comment: As Frank suggested - Try changing `url: '/login/email',` to `url: '/email',`

Comment: If you access /login/login/email this link into browser you will see logs are print in order.

Comment: Thank you for finding the url mistake, fixed that so it won't cause any problems.

Nonetheless, the child controller is still not running

Comment: Share you Html code as well. We have clear understanding about views

Comment: Ok I can't really share my html code.

My understanding is that there needs to be a 
    ui-view='email'

element in the html. I thought this needed to be in the child template, but that wasn't working. I tried adding that to the parent and now it works!

But... this leaves me with one problem. How am I supposed to know which of the children views is to be loaded? Using ng-if/ng-switch and having that bound to some variable in the parent controller?
I thought that was the whole point of having different states for different views: so that the controller doesn't need to do that logic.

Comment: The value of `ui-view="..."` is usually something generic, and it's used to reference a child view from the router. It's more useful when you have multiple child views displayed at the same time. If you have only one child view, you can just name it something generic like `main` instead of `email`. You might not even need to name it all - check the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use default view set for state.

```
...
views: {
    '': {
           controller: 'loginController'
     }
}
...
```

```
...
views: {
      '': {
          controller: 'loginEmailController',
          templateUrl: '/components/loginEmail/loginEmailView.html'
      }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the larger of the many problems I was having.

Basically, by giving my view a name ("email"), it wasn't being loaded.

Additionally, I also needed to include an empty ui-view in the parent state. Put those two together and it started working :)